# constructor CountDownTimer in class CountDownTimer cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android

I am receiving the following error:

```
Error:(104, 51) error: constructor CountDownTimer in class CountDownTimer cannot be applied to given types;
    required: long,long
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here is my code:

```
class C06964 extends CountDownTimer {

    /* renamed from: com.aplikasi.gokil.MyActivity.4.1 */
    class C06941 extends CountDownTimer {
        final /* synthetic */ Toast val$toast;

        C06941(long x0, long x1, Toast toast) {
            this.val$toast = toast;
            super(x0, x1);
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            this.val$toast.show();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            this.val$toast.cancel();
        }
    }

    /* renamed from: com.aplikasi.gokil.MyActivity.4.2 */
    class C06952 extends CountDownTimer {
        final /* synthetic */ Toast val$toast;

        C06952(long x0, long x1, Toast toast) {
            this.val$toast = toast;
            super(x0, x1);
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            this.val$toast.show();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            this.val$toast.cancel();
            MyActivity.this.startActivity(IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(MyActivity.this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(MyActivity.this.getPackageName()).getComponent()));
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    C06964(long x0, long x1) {
        super(x0, x1);
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        ((TextView) MyActivity.this.findViewById(id.textView)).setText("Restart Application In : " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this.getBaseContext(), "Restart Application In : " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000), 0);
        toast.show();
        new C06941(1000, 1000, toast).start();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this.getBaseContext(), "Restarting Application...", 0);
        toast.show();
        ((TextView) MyActivity.this.findViewById(id.textView)).setText("Restarting Application...");
        new C06952(3000, 3000, toast).start();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 3):

> Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor. - [Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Your cunstructors are calling `super(x0, x1)` after setting `this.val$toast = toast`.